# esp32 arduino ide client)How can you print it out in HEX?

Tags: c++, esp32

```
static void notifyCallback( 
  BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic, 
  uint8_t* pData,
  size_t length,
  bool isNotify) 
{
  Serial.print("data length: ");
  Serial.println(length);
  Serial.print("data: ");
  Serial.println(*pData,HEX);
}
```

pData is received in the uint8_t* type.
but I want to print it out in hex form.
So I wrote Serial.println(*pData,HEX);
How should I fix this?

Comment: What is the output? It look fine... with the HEX.. Did you checkout with a cast to uint_8? Serial.println( (uint8_t)(*pData), HEX ); or Serial.println( ( pData[0], HEX );

Comment: data length : 5
data : 2
only this output

Comment: That means, you got an array of 5 elements with the pData. You can access these values with pData[i] .. where i is in the range from 0 to 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Byte array \[in Hex\] to Char array or String type + Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748740/convert-byte-array-in-hex-to-char-array-or-string-type-arduino)

Answer (score 0):

You could access the array elements of pData. The amount of values is given in length.

```
static void notifyCallback( 
  BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic, 
  uint8_t* pData,
  size_t length,
  bool isNotify ) 
{
  Serial.print( "data length: " );
  Serial.println( length );
  for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
  {
    Serial.print( "data: " );
    Serial.println( pData[i], HEX );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is pointer, but i forgot it.